# MySQL Union into New Column

Tags: mysql, join, union

Say I have two tables:

```
table_A    table_B
+----+     +----+
| id |     | id |
+----+     +----+
| 1  |     | 3  |
| 2  |     | 4  |
+----+     +----+
```

What I want is the `UNION` of the tables, but with the records from table_B as a separate column, rather than additional rows. There doesn't need to be any correlation between the rows, such as in the case of a `JOIN`.

An example result set would look like:

```
+------+------+
| a.id | b.id |
+------+------+
| 1    | 3    |
| 2    | 4    |
+------+------+
```

I can get close with

```
SELECT a.id, b.id FROM 
(SELECT id, 'nothing' from table_A) a JOIN 
(SELECT id, 'nothing' from table_B) b ON a.nothing = b.nothing
```

but this creates twice as many rows as needed:

```
+------+------+
| a.id | b.id |
+------+------+
|    1 |    3 |
|    2 |    3 |
|    1 |    4 |
|    2 |    4 |
+------+------+
```

and `GROUP BY` on `a.id` or `b.id` loses one of the values from the column that isn't grouped.

The size of each table can vary. If one table is larger than the other, `NULL` values should be placed in the shorter column.

Comment: Are the number of rows of the tables same?  What if, say, `a` has more rows than `b`?

Comment: There may be an easier solution by doing two queries and combining them in php or whatever language you are using. I'm interested to know the real life problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @leeyuiwah The size of each table can vary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non trivial &

And now tested: [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96cadb/2/0)
And now updated to handle requirement of including all records from both tables.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96cadb/4/0)

I would assign each row in each table a specific row number using a user variable and then join on the user variable.  The reason why joining on a pseudo column value 'nothing' doesn't work is that, as you see, it uses EACH ID once for each value in the other table thus resulting in a 1:M when you need a 1:1.  By assigning a row number, we guarantee each row is only used once; thus a 1:1 relationship.

This assumes if both tables have unequal rows that the table having more records will cutoff eliminating the higher row numbers is acceptable.

If you wanted, you could use an outer (left,right) join so that all records of the table with more IDs shows, but you would have to know which table has more first.

```
SELECT C.ID, D.ID
FROM (SELECT id, @row:=@row+1  RN
      FROM table_A
      CROSS JOIN (select @row:=0) a
      ORDER BY ID) C
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, @row2:=@row2+1 RN
            FROM table_B
            CROSS JOIN (select @row2:=0) b
            ORDER BY ID) D
on C.RN = D.RN
```

I also applied an order by so that the lower ids of each table are aligned.

Now if you don't knowwhich table will have more records...

You can simulate a full outer join in MYSQL with the following...

```
SELECT C.ID, D.ID
FROM (SELECT id, @row:=@row+1  RN
      FROM table_A
      CROSS JOIN (select @row:=0) a
      ORDER BY ID) C
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, @row2:=@row2+1 RN
            FROM table_B
            CROSS JOIN (select @row2:=0) b
            ORDER BY ID) D
on C.RN = D.RN

UNION

SELECT C.ID, D.ID
FROM (SELECT id, @row:=@row+1  RN
      FROM table_A
      CROSS JOIN (select @row:=0) a
      ORDER BY ID) C
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT id, @row2:=@row2+1 RN
            FROM table_B
            CROSS JOIN (select @row2:=0) b
            ORDER BY ID) D
on C.RN = D.RN
```

Notice `union` vs `union all`

Union does a distinct which will remove duplicates which wouldn't occur when using a `union all`

Comment: The `SELECT @row...` statements need their own aliases as well, but other than that this seems to work.

Comment: This works when the table row counts match, but it can't handle mismatched row counts in the two tables.

Comment: Agreed which is why I stated the following two things: 1) This assumes if both tables have unequal rows that the table having more records will cutoff eliminating the higher row numbers is acceptable.

2) If you wanted, you could use an outer (left,right) join so that all records of the table with more IDs shows, but you would have to know which table has more first.

Comment: Or you could use two outer joins and a UNION, as I did in my answer.

Comment: Umm... vague requirements lead to different answers.

Comment: @xQbert yup :-)

Comment: & it looks like my assumption made one of me :P

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I'm going to mark this as the solution because @xQbert addressed the problem as I stated it, and then updated it when I clarified, but you're both right.

Comment: I don't care which is picked to be honest I just want you to understand the choices and variances in the solutions provided.  Could you do this by yourself next time?  ROW_NUMBER() using user variables and two data sets to create the full outer join and union doing the distinct to eliminate duplicates!

Answer (score 2):

you can also do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT ra.id, rb.id
FROM (
    select @anr:=(@anr+1) as nr, a.* from table_a  a JOIN (SELECT @anr:=0 ) as init ) ra
LEFT JOIN (
    select @bnr:=(@bnr+1) as nr, b.* from table_b  b JOIN (SELECT @bnr:=0 ) as init ) rb
    ON ra.nr = rb.nr;
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [l]> select * from table_a;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]> select * from table_b;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
|  4 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]> SELECT ra.id, rb.id
    -> FROM (
    ->     select @anr:=(@anr+1) as nr, a.* from table_a  a JOIN (SELECT @anr:=0 ) as init ) ra
    -> LEFT JOIN (
    ->     select @bnr:=(@bnr+1) as nr, b.* from table_b  b JOIN (SELECT @bnr:=0 ) as init ) rb
    ->     ON ra.nr = rb.nr;
+----+------+
| id | id   |
+----+------+
|  1 |    2 |
|  2 |    4 |
+----+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [l]>
```

Comment: This works when the table row counts match, but it can't handle mismatched row counts in the two tables.

Comment: Untrue, it works fine if A has more records than B or if they match just not if B has more than A (but then maybe it doesn't matter and they only need combinations for the lowest rowcount table...

Comment: I tested this by inserting into one of the columns, and it correctly appends NULL to the shorter column.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for the correction. I used two outer joins and a UNION in my answer to handle both cases.

Answer (score 2):

You need two features that MySQL doesn't have:

1. Row ids (so you can join the matching rows from the two tables)
2. Full outer join (to cover both cases where table_A has more rows, or when table_B has more rows)

In order to work around those missing features, you can use a query like this:

```
select a.id,b.id
from 
(
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, t1.id
FROM ( 
   select id from table_A order by id
) t1,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r1
) a
left outer join 
(
SELECT @rownum2:=@rownum2 + 1 as row_number, t2.id
FROM ( 
   select id from table_B order by id
) t2,
(SELECT @rownum2 := 0) r2
) b on b.row_number = a.row_number
union 
select c.id,d.id
from 
(
SELECT @rownum3:=@rownum3 + 1 as row_number, t3.id
FROM ( 
   select id from table_A order by id
) t3,
(SELECT @rownum3 := 0) r3
) c
right outer join 
(
SELECT @rownum4:=@rownum4 + 1 as row_number, t4.id
FROM ( 
   select id from table_B order by id
) t4,
(SELECT @rownum4 := 0) r4
) d on d.row_number = c.row_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined a couple of the answers:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id FROM
(
  SELECT @ca:=(@ca+1) as c FROM table_a JOIN (SELECT @ca:=0) as init
  UNION
  SELECT @cb:=(@cb+1) as c FROM table_b JOIN (SELECT @cb:=0) as init
) as maxrows
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT @c2:=(@c2+1) as c2, id FROM table_a JOIN (SELECT @c2:=0) as init
) as A on (c = c2)
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT @c3:=(@c3+1) as c3, id  FROM table_b JOIN (SELECT @c3:=0) as init
) as B on (c = c3)
```

The first union gets the the maximum number of rows (in case the two tables have different number of rows), and then we can simply left join it to the numbered tables.